Issue with LSTM input shape in Keras: Inconsistent shape (1, 3, 17) vs. (1, 12, 17)
Description:
I'm working on a time series forecasting project using LSTM in Keras. I'm facing an issue with the input shape inconsistency when I try to change the sequence length (n_input) from 3 to 12.
Problem:
I have a dataset with the following shape:
scaled_train.shape: (156, 17)
When I define my TimeseriesGenerator with a sequence length of 3 (n_input = 3), everything works fine. However, when I try to change n_input to 12, I encounter an issue with the input shape mismatch.
Here's a snippet of my code:
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import TimeseriesGenerator

n_input = 12
n_features = 1
batch_size = 1
generator = TimeseriesGenerator(scaled_train, scaled_train, length=n_input, batch_size=batch_size)

# Define and compile the LSTM model
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(100, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_input, n_features)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')

# Fit the model
model.fit(generator, epochs=50)

Error Message:
When I run the code with n_input = 12, I receive the following error:

ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 12, 17)

Additional Information:

I've ensured that my input data (scaled_train) has the shape (156, 17).
The error seems to be related to the shape of the input data. It's expecting a 3-dimensional input, but the shape is correct as (1, 12, 17).
Request:
I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue and correctly set up the LSTM model with a sequence length of 12.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Here's my entire code

`
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.read_csv('sensor_data.csv',index_col='created_at',parse_dates=True)
df.head()
df.plot(figsize=(12,6))
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose
results = seasonal_decompose(df['PM2_5'], period=1)
results.plot()
len(df)
train = df.iloc[:156]
test = df.iloc[156:]
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
df.head(),df.tail()
scaler.fit(train)
scaled_train = scaler.transform(train)
scaled_test = scaler.transform(test)
scaled_train[:10]
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import TimeseriesGenerator
# define generator
n_input = 3
n_features = 1
generator = TimeseriesGenerator(scaled_train, scaled_train, length=n_input, batch_size=1)
X,y = generator[0]
print(f'Given the Array: \n{X.flatten()}')
print(f'Predict this y: \n {y}')
X.shape
# We do the same thing, but now instead for 12 months
# n_input = 12
# generator = TimeseriesGenerator(scaled_train, scaled_train, length=n_input, batch_size=1)

n_input = 12
n_features = 1
batch_size = 1

generator = TimeseriesGenerator(scaled_train, scaled_train, length=n_input, batch_size=batch_size)
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
# define model
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(100, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_input, n_features)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
model.summary()
# fit model
model.fit(generator,epochs=50)
`

